# Game crashes on start for unknown reason

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have a unity3d project which, up to previous build, ran with no issues on android.
It is already set up to use the new google play store package format, which gets correctly accepted on the play store. The previous build, even with all of play store settings filled in, worked correctly when built in the pure non-play store .apk and copied to device and installed from the file.

Afterwards, the only change I made was adding a single clause into if condition in the code (which was just "if(false && originalCondition)", the intention was to disable that part of code, it's not relevant to the issue, it was part of code that handled starting and stopping particle effect within the gameplay), and now when I build it as an apk, and install it manually on the phone, and try to run it, it crashes immediately in the typical way of the screen flashing black for a moment as it creates the window, and then I'm back to the phone's desktop.

I have absolutely no idea why, and absolutely no idea how to find out why, let alone how to fix it... :/

If anyone has any idea how to at least find out what the issue actually is, please let me know/help. Write any and all suggestions as "answers" even if they're not, please, since I don't think I'll get an actual answer solving the problem, just pointers on how to proceed, and since comments have length limit and no formatting, thanks. (If this request doesn't violate some SO rules)

Below is content of the logcat from adb bridge, caught via Android Studio, filtered on the term "unity".

```
2019-12-03 10:57:02.619 12052-12052/? D/Unity: CommandLine:  
2019-12-03 10:57:02.692 12052-12052/? D/HwRTBlurUtils: check blur style for HwPhoneWindow, themeResId : 0x7f030001, context : com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity@d57310b, Nhwext : 0, get Blur : disable with , null
2019-12-03 10:57:02.693 12052-12052/? D/HwRTBlurUtils: check blur style for HwPhoneWindow, themeResId : 0x7f030001, context : com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity@d57310b, Nhwext : 0, get Blur : disable with , null
2019-12-03 10:57:02.698 12052-12052/? D/ActivityThread: add activity client record, r= ActivityRecord{492b683 token=android.os.BinderProxy@61b8bfc {com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}} token= android.os.BinderProxy@61b8bfc
2019-12-03 10:57:02.700 12052-12052/? I/Unity: onResume
2019-12-03 10:57:02.728 1161-5474/? V/WindowManager: Adding Window{8ec992a u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity} to AppWindowToken{1b8f6c3 token=Token{1e10272 ActivityRecord{7de437d u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t18725}}}
2019-12-03 10:57:02.729 1161-5474/? V/WindowManager: addWindow: New client android.os.BinderProxy@dc3a215: window=Window{8ec992a u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity} Callers=com.android.server.wm.HwWindowManagerService.addWindow:585 com.android.server.wm.Session.addToDisplay:199 android.view.IWindowSession$Stub.onTransact:124 com.android.server.wm.Session.onTransact:161 android.os.Binder.execTransact:675 
2019-12-03 10:57:02.758 1161-5474/? V/WindowManager: Relayout window turning screen on: Window{8ec992a u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
2019-12-03 10:57:02.761 1161-5474/? W/WindowManager: EGLdebug Created surface WindowStateAnimator{1131df6 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
2019-12-03 10:57:02.764 1161-5474/? V/HwPhoneWindowManager: updateSystemUiColorLw window=Window{8ec992a u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity},EmuiStyle=0,StatusBarColor=0xff757575,NavigationBarColor=0xff000000, mLastIsEmuiLightStyle=-1, mForceNotchStatusBar=false
2019-12-03 10:57:02.817 12052-12096/? D/Unity: SetWindow 0 0x71055cf010
2019-12-03 10:57:02.817 12052-12096/? D/Unity: SetWindow 0 0x71055cf010
2019-12-03 10:57:02.832 1161-1442/? V/WindowManager: Relayout window turning screen on: Window{8ec992a u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
2019-12-03 10:57:02.834 631-631/? D/SurfaceFlinger: duplicate layer name: changing com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity to com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity#1
2019-12-03 10:57:02.836 1161-1442/? W/WindowManager: EGLdebug Created surface WindowStateAnimator{1131df6 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
2019-12-03 10:57:02.871 1161-6923/? D/WindowManager: finishDrawingWindow: Window{8ec992a u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity} mDrawState=DRAW_PENDING
2019-12-03 10:57:02.873 12052-12052/? I/Unity: windowFocusChanged: true
2019-12-03 10:57:02.888 1161-1297/? I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroyDeferredSurfaceLocked:928 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroyPreservedSurfaceLocked:651 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.destroyPreservedSurfaceLocked:6128 com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.animate:295 com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.lambda$-com_android_server_wm_WindowAnimator_4498:115 com.android.server.wm.-$Lambda$OQfQhd_xsxt9hoLAjIbVfOwa-jY$1.$m$0:4 com.android.server.wm.-$Lambda$OQfQhd_xsxt9hoLAjIbVfOwa-jY$1.doFrame:0 android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run:979 
2019-12-03 10:57:02.889 12052-12096/? D/Unity: Enabling Unity systrace
2019-12-03 10:57:02.890 1161-1635/? D/WindowManager: finishDrawingWindow: Window{8ec992a u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity} mDrawState=HAS_DRAWN
2019-12-03 10:57:02.916 12052-12096/? D/Unity: [VFS] Mount /data/app/com.shcode.HordeMode-cAAp2ork2yKluy8z7dn18w==/base.apk
2019-12-03 10:57:03.033 1161-1442/? V/WindowManager: Relayout window turning screen on: Window{8ec992a u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
2019-12-03 10:57:03.045 12052-12096/? I/Unity: SystemInfo CPU = ARM64 FP ASIMD AES, Cores = 8, Memory = 2780mb
2019-12-03 10:57:03.045 12052-12096/? I/Unity: SystemInfo ARM big.LITTLE configuration: 4 big (mask: 0xf0), 4 little (mask: 0xf)
2019-12-03 10:57:03.045 12052-12096/? I/Unity: ApplicationInfo com.shcode.HordeMode version 0.1 build f49be701-4d6c-4e19-a7a9-b14406456042
2019-12-03 10:57:03.046 12052-12096/? I/Unity: Built from '2019.2/staging' branch, Version '2019.2.0f1 (20c1667945cf)', Build type 'Development', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'arm64-v8a', Stripping 'Enabled'
2019-12-03 10:57:03.067 1161-1297/? V/WindowManager: Removing Window{3a2a258 u0 Splash Screen com.shcode.HordeMode} from AppWindowToken{1b8f6c3 token=Token{1e10272 ActivityRecord{7de437d u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t18725}}}
2019-12-03 10:57:03.075 1161-1635/? V/WindowManager: Relayout window turning screen on: Window{8ec992a u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
2019-12-03 10:57:03.088 12052-12096/? D/Unity: PlayerConnection initialized from /data/app/com.shcode.HordeMode-cAAp2ork2yKluy8z7dn18w==/base.apk/assets/bin/Data (debug = 0)
2019-12-03 10:57:03.089 12052-12096/? D/Unity: PlayerConnection initialized network socket : 0.0.0.0 55456
2019-12-03 10:57:03.089 12052-12096/? D/Unity: PlayerConnection initialized unix socket : Unity-com.shcode.HordeMode
2019-12-03 10:57:03.092 12052-12096/? D/Unity: Multi-casting "[IP] 192.168.1.104 [Port] 55456 [Flags] 2 [Guid] 128027842 [EditorId] 4122807452 [Version] 1048832 [Id] AndroidPlayer(HUAWEI_WAS-LX1@192.168.1.104) [Debug] 0 [PackageName] AndroidPlayer" to [225.0.0.222:54997]...
2019-12-03 10:57:03.092 12052-12096/? D/Unity: Started listening to [0.0.0.0:55456]
2019-12-03 10:57:03.116 1161-1442/? D/WindowManager: finishDrawingWindow: Window{8ec992a u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity} mDrawState=HAS_DRAWN
2019-12-03 10:57:03.151 1161-1678/? V/WindowManager: Relayout window turning screen on: Window{8ec992a u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
2019-12-03 10:57:03.163 12052-12096/? E/CRASH: pid: 12052, tid: 12096, name: UnityMain  >>> com.shcode.HordeMode <<<
2019-12-03 10:57:03.294 1161-3606/? I/WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{8ec992a u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
2019-12-03 10:57:03.295 1161-3606/? V/WindowManager: removeIfPossible: Window{8ec992a u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity} callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.-wrap1:0 com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied:2481 android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice:840 <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> 
2019-12-03 10:57:03.295 1161-3606/? W/WindowManager: Keyguard is occluded and there is no window in AppWindowToken{1b8f6c3 token=Token{1e10272 ActivityRecord{7de437d u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t18725}}}
2019-12-03 10:57:03.296 1161-3606/? I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2089 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:899 com.android.server.wm.HwWindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:1006 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeImmediately:1899 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeIfPossible:2051 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.-wrap1:0 com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied:2481 android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice:840 
2019-12-03 10:57:03.297 1161-3608/? W/ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{7de437d u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t18725}: app died, no saved state
2019-12-03 10:57:03.301 1161-3606/? W/WindowManager: Exception thrown when updateSurfaceStatusWindowStateAnimator{1131df6 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}: android.os.DeadObjectException
2019-12-03 10:57:03.301 1161-3606/? V/WindowManager: postWindowRemoveCleanupLocked: Window{8ec992a u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
2019-12-03 10:57:03.301 1161-3606/? V/WindowManager: Removing Window{8ec992a u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity} from AppWindowToken{1b8f6c3 token=Token{1e10272 ActivityRecord{7de437d u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t18725}}}
2019-12-03 10:57:03.308 1161-3608/? V/WindowManager: removeAppToken: AppWindowToken{1b8f6c3 token=Token{1e10272 ActivityRecord{7de437d u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t18725}}} delayed=false Callers=com.android.server.wm.DisplayContent.removeAppToken:994 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowContainerController.removeContainer:352 com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord.removeWindowContainer:1045 com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.removeActivityFromHistoryLocked:4486 
2019-12-03 11:02:14.119 1161-3607/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity bnds=[804,656][1068,942]} from uid 10062
2019-12-03 11:02:14.123 1161-3607/? I/ActivityManager: ActivityRecord info: ActivityInfo{2b18ee6 com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
2019-12-03 11:02:14.129 1161-3607/? V/WindowManager: addAppToken: AppWindowToken{777b372 token=Token{9cd187d ActivityRecord{8320ed4 u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t18726}}} controller={TaskWindowContainerController taskId=18726} at 2147483647
2019-12-03 11:02:14.149 1161-1297/? V/WindowManager: Adding Window{f46783b u0 Splash Screen com.shcode.HordeMode} to AppWindowToken{777b372 token=Token{9cd187d ActivityRecord{8320ed4 u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t18726}}}
2019-12-03 11:02:14.175 1161-3607/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 12590:com.shcode.HordeMode/u0a243 for activity com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity
2019-12-03 11:02:14.177 1161-3607/? V/WindowManager: No longer Stopped: AppWindowToken{777b372 token=Token{9cd187d ActivityRecord{8320ed4 u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t18726}}}
2019-12-03 11:02:14.177 1161-3607/? V/WindowManager: No longer Stopped: AppWindowToken{777b372 token=Token{9cd187d ActivityRecord{8320ed4 u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t18726}}}
2019-12-03 11:02:14.235 1161-1646/? V/WindowManager: No longer Stopped: AppWindowToken{777b372 token=Token{9cd187d ActivityRecord{8320ed4 u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t18726}}}
2019-12-03 11:02:14.251 1161-1646/? V/WindowManager: Check opening app=AppWindowToken{777b372 token=Token{9cd187d ActivityRecord{8320ed4 u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t18726}}}: allDrawn=false startingDisplayed=true startingMoved=false isRelaunching()=false
2019-12-03 11:02:14.407 12590-12590/? D/Unity: CommandLine:  
2019-12-03 11:02:14.451 12590-12590/? D/HwRTBlurUtils: check blur style for HwPhoneWindow, themeResId : 0x7f030001, context : com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity@8936be8, Nhwext : 0, get Blur : disable with , null
2019-12-03 11:02:14.456 12590-12590/? D/ActivityThread: add activity client record, r= ActivityRecord{265d000 token=android.os.BinderProxy@f499285 {com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}} token= android.os.BinderProxy@f499285
2019-12-03 11:02:14.452 12590-12590/? D/HwRTBlurUtils: check blur style for HwPhoneWindow, themeResId : 0x7f030001, context : com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity@8936be8, Nhwext : 0, get Blur : disable with , null
2019-12-03 11:02:14.458 12590-12590/? I/Unity: onResume
2019-12-03 11:02:14.483 1161-1175/? V/WindowManager: Adding Window{522a96e u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity} to AppWindowToken{777b372 token=Token{9cd187d ActivityRecord{8320ed4 u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t18726}}}
2019-12-03 11:02:14.484 1161-1175/? V/WindowManager: addWindow: New client android.os.BinderProxy@92a78e9: window=Window{522a96e u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity} Callers=com.android.server.wm.HwWindowManagerService.addWindow:585 com.android.server.wm.Session.addToDisplay:199 android.view.IWindowSession$Stub.onTransact:124 com.android.server.wm.Session.onTransact:161 android.os.Binder.execTransact:675 
2019-12-03 11:02:14.502 1161-1646/? V/WindowManager: Relayout window turning screen on: Window{522a96e u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
2019-12-03 11:02:14.504 1161-1646/? W/WindowManager: EGLdebug Created surface WindowStateAnimator{875d80f com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
2019-12-03 11:02:14.505 1161-1646/? V/HwPhoneWindowManager: updateSystemUiColorLw window=Window{522a96e u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity},EmuiStyle=0,StatusBarColor=0xff757575,NavigationBarColor=0xff000000, mLastIsEmuiLightStyle=-1, mForceNotchStatusBar=false
2019-12-03 11:02:14.561 12590-12611/? D/Unity: SetWindow 0 0x70f5720010
2019-12-03 11:02:14.563 12590-12611/? D/Unity: SetWindow 0 0x70f5720010
2019-12-03 11:02:14.563 12590-12590/? I/Unity: windowFocusChanged: true
2019-12-03 11:02:14.568 1161-1175/? V/WindowManager: Relayout window turning screen on: Window{522a96e u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
2019-12-03 11:02:14.569 631-631/? D/SurfaceFlinger: duplicate layer name: changing com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity to com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity#1
2019-12-03 11:02:14.571 1161-1175/? W/WindowManager: EGLdebug Created surface WindowStateAnimator{875d80f com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
2019-12-03 11:02:14.579 12590-12611/? D/Unity: Enabling Unity systrace
2019-12-03 11:02:14.595 1161-1175/? D/WindowManager: finishDrawingWindow: Window{522a96e u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity} mDrawState=DRAW_PENDING
2019-12-03 11:02:14.596 12590-12611/? D/Unity: [VFS] Mount /data/app/com.shcode.HordeMode-cAAp2ork2yKluy8z7dn18w==/base.apk
2019-12-03 11:02:14.607 1161-1189/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity: +454ms
2019-12-03 11:02:14.607 1161-1189/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity: +454ms
2019-12-03 11:02:14.617 1161-1297/? I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroyDeferredSurfaceLocked:928 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroyPreservedSurfaceLocked:651 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.destroyPreservedSurfaceLocked:6128 com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.animate:295 com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.lambda$-com_android_server_wm_WindowAnimator_4498:115 com.android.server.wm.-$Lambda$OQfQhd_xsxt9hoLAjIbVfOwa-jY$1.$m$0:4 com.android.server.wm.-$Lambda$OQfQhd_xsxt9hoLAjIbVfOwa-jY$1.doFrame:0 android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run:979 
2019-12-03 11:02:14.623 12590-12611/? I/Unity: SystemInfo CPU = ARM64 FP ASIMD AES, Cores = 8, Memory = 2780mb
2019-12-03 11:02:14.623 12590-12611/? I/Unity: SystemInfo ARM big.LITTLE configuration: 4 big (mask: 0xf0), 4 little (mask: 0xf)
2019-12-03 11:02:14.624 12590-12611/? I/Unity: ApplicationInfo com.shcode.HordeMode version 0.1 build f49be701-4d6c-4e19-a7a9-b14406456042
2019-12-03 11:02:14.624 12590-12611/? I/Unity: Built from '2019.2/staging' branch, Version '2019.2.0f1 (20c1667945cf)', Build type 'Development', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'arm64-v8a', Stripping 'Enabled'
2019-12-03 11:02:14.629 1161-1646/? V/WindowManager: Relayout window turning screen on: Window{522a96e u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
2019-12-03 11:02:14.646 12590-12611/? D/Unity: PlayerConnection initialized from /data/app/com.shcode.HordeMode-cAAp2ork2yKluy8z7dn18w==/base.apk/assets/bin/Data (debug = 0)
2019-12-03 11:02:14.647 12590-12611/? D/Unity: PlayerConnection initialized network socket : 0.0.0.0 55050
2019-12-03 11:02:14.647 12590-12611/? D/Unity: PlayerConnection initialized unix socket : Unity-com.shcode.HordeMode
2019-12-03 11:02:14.649 12590-12611/? D/Unity: Multi-casting "[IP] 192.168.1.104 [Port] 55050 [Flags] 2 [Guid] 2203760397 [EditorId] 4122807452 [Version] 1048832 [Id] AndroidPlayer(HUAWEI_WAS-LX1@192.168.1.104) [Debug] 0 [PackageName] AndroidPlayer" to [225.0.0.222:54997]...
2019-12-03 11:02:14.649 12590-12611/? D/Unity: Started listening to [0.0.0.0:55050]
2019-12-03 11:02:14.679 1161-1175/? D/WindowManager: finishDrawingWindow: Window{522a96e u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity} mDrawState=HAS_DRAWN
2019-12-03 11:02:14.693 12590-12611/? E/CRASH: pid: 12590, tid: 12611, name: UnityMain  >>> com.shcode.HordeMode <<<
2019-12-03 11:02:14.778 1161-1297/? V/WindowManager: Removing Window{f46783b u0 Splash Screen com.shcode.HordeMode} from AppWindowToken{777b372 token=Token{9cd187d ActivityRecord{8320ed4 u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t18726}}}
2019-12-03 11:02:14.783 1161-1323/? W/InputDispatcher: channel '522a96e com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
2019-12-03 11:02:14.783 1161-1323/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '522a96e com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2019-12-03 11:02:14.786 1161-9242/? W/ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{8320ed4 u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t18726}: app died, no saved state
2019-12-03 11:02:14.799 1161-9242/? I/WindowManager: Failed to capture screenshot of Token{9cd187d ActivityRecord{8320ed4 u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t18726 f}} appWin=Window{522a96e u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity} drawState=4
2019-12-03 11:02:14.799 1161-9242/? V/WindowManager: removeAppToken: AppWindowToken{777b372 token=Token{9cd187d ActivityRecord{8320ed4 u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t18726}}} delayed=false Callers=com.android.server.wm.DisplayContent.removeAppToken:994 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowContainerController.removeContainer:352 com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord.removeWindowContainer:1045 com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.removeActivityFromHistoryLocked:4486 
2019-12-03 11:02:14.799 1161-9242/? V/WindowManager: removeIfPossible: Window{522a96e u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity} callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeIfPossible:1914 com.android.server.wm.WindowToken.removeAllWindowsIfPossible:139 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.removeIfPossible:556 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.onRemovedFromDisplay:623 com.android.server.wm.DisplayContent.removeAppToken:994 
2019-12-03 11:02:14.799 1161-9242/? W/InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '522a96e com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity (server)'
2019-12-03 11:02:14.799 1161-9242/? W/WindowManager: Keyguard is occluded and there is no window in AppWindowToken{777b372 token=Token{9cd187d ActivityRecord{8320ed4 u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t18726}}}
2019-12-03 11:02:14.800 1161-9242/? I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2089 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:899 com.android.server.wm.HwWindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:1006 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeImmediately:1899 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeIfPossible:2051 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeIfPossible:1914 com.android.server.wm.WindowToken.removeAllWindowsIfPossible:139 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.removeIfPossible:556 
2019-12-03 11:02:14.800 1161-9242/? W/WindowManager: Exception thrown when updateSurfaceStatusWindowStateAnimator{875d80f com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}: android.os.DeadObjectException
2019-12-03 11:02:14.800 1161-9242/? V/WindowManager: postWindowRemoveCleanupLocked: Window{522a96e u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
2019-12-03 11:02:14.800 1161-9242/? V/WindowManager: Removing Window{522a96e u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity} from AppWindowToken{777b372 token=Token{9cd187d ActivityRecord{8320ed4 u0 com.shcode.HordeMode/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t18726}}}
```

Comment: try to logcat with "FATAL" filter

Comment: @NikolayGonza FATAL filter gives back no results. Literally nothing.

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems this is bug in the unity version I'm using: 2019.2.0f1

The problem (as described here) seems to be that the game uses old il2cpp files with the new build (if the phone has Backup and Automatic Restore options enabled). Fix is deleting Android/data/ folder on the phone itself, since Unity re-creates those files on launch if they're missing.

Another way to fix this would be, I assume, switching the build format from il2cpp to anything else.

Lastly, this issue is fixed in Unity 2019.2.6

[Link to bug report in Unity tracker, which also contains detailed explanation of the fix itself and why it (probably) works.](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/android-il2cpp-app-crashes-on-2019-dot-1-0a12-and-up-on-launch-if-old-il2cpp-files-from-2019-dot-1-0a11-and-below-are-backuped)